# How can I improve Neo4j relation save time

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am currently using neo4j 2.3.3 via the spring data library.
I run on Window 7 OS and use Java 1.8 as the JVM.
I am running in Embedded mode.

I am saving down around 20,000 relations and its taking about
15 minutes.
The nodes are already present in the database.

I am ultimately using the following method to perform my save.

```
@Repository
public class GraphRepositoryImpl<T> implements GraphRepository<T> {
 :
    @Override
    public <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> ses, int depth) {
        neo4jOperations.save(ses, depth);
        return ses;
    }
:
}
```

Note: I have tried setting the depth to 0 and -1 but this does not seem to 
alter the save time.

I have profiled the executable using Java Mission Control and noted that
it spends 20% of its time in the following method:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.StorePropertyPayloadCursor.currentBlocksUsed()  7,176   19.846%
```

which was ultimately called from:

```
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_3$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(GraphDatabaseAPI, TransactionInfo, CypherExecutionMode, Map, QuerySession) 7,658   21.179%
```

The actual save hook takes up about 10% of the time:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.save(Object, int) 3,817   10.556%
```

I also have the JMC recording; see [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7lcn9to0n9i5gv/flight_recording_18092Xms1024M7012_2_so.jfr?dl=0).